# Problema con validacion if, else if con jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, condiciones

Les expongo toda mi función. Primero hace una validación de campos, si no son nulos continúa...Después en php imprimo dos posibles respuestas dependiendo de la consulta si el password es correcto envía "next_money" de lo contrario "error_money".

Mi problema viene cuando intento validar la respuesta del data, si imprimo en la alerta el resultado del data todo es correcto, sin embargo como menciona a la hora de validar no hace nada o bien aunque evalúe el primer if se pasa al segundo. Creen que mi problema venga o sea necesario formatear mi data como string? De antemano agradezco su ayuda.

```
function valida() {
            if (document.formAction.qty.value == 0) {
                $("#qty_INVALID").show();
                $("#qty").css('border-color', 'red').focus(); 
                return 0;         
            }
            if (document.formAction.password.value == 0) {
                $("#password_INVALID").show();
                $("#password").css('border-color', 'red').focus(); 
                return 0;         
            }
            //Enviar datos
            var qty = $("#qty").val();
            var password = $("#password").val(); 
            var dataPost ="qty="+qty+"&pass="+password+"&moneyOut";
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "data/insert.php",
                data: dataPost,
                dataType: 'html',
                cache: false,
                success: function(data) {   
                    alert(data);
                    if(data=="next_money") {
                        alert("cierra modal");
                        //$("#retiroModal").modal("hide");                               
                    } else if(data="error_money"){
                        alert("activa errores");
                        /*$("#password").val(''); 
                        $("#password").css('border-color', 'red').focus(); 
                        $("#alerta_pass").fadeIn("fast");  */
                    }

                }
            })
        }
```

Comment: Ojo que aquí estas haciendo una asignación en vez de una comparación: } else if(data="error_money"){

Comment: Como bien dice @ordago, aquí haces una asignación: `data="error_money"` no una comparación. Además , ¿por qué usas `else if` si al parecer hay solamente dos opciones posibles?. Por otra parte, todo esto lo puedes simplificar con un ternario, poniendo solamente: **`var msg= ( data=="next_money" ) ? "cierra modal" : "activa errores"; alert (msg);`** Ahí `msg` adquirirá uno u otro valor según el caso y luego imprimes `msg`. Tampoco veo qué sentido tiene que en `dataPost`
 envíes `&moneyOut` sin ningún valor adjunto.

Comment: Gracias por sus comentarios, con respecto a que puse solo un = entiendo que es asignación, pero fue un error de dedo a la hora de hacer el post y editar, sin embargo lo tengo bien y también he probado solo usar un else, y tampoco funciona, en verdad algo tan simple nunca me había vuelto loco, no entiendo que esta pasando.

Comment: De hecho ya quedó así:

success: function(data) {   
                        if(data=="next_money") {
                            alert("cierra modal");
                        } else {
                            alert("activa errores");
                        }                        
                    }
Y siempre se pasa al **else **, es decir, nunca se cumple la primera condición.

Comment: ¿Qué valor exactamente te imprime el `alert(data)`? ¿Has mirado a ver si tiene espacios en blanco la respuesta? Si data vale `"next_money     "`, te va a dar false al comparar con `"next_money"` Puedes ver si tiene espacios poniendo `alert('"' + data + '"');`